# removing trailing zeros in ssrs but keeping the other decimal values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How to remove the zeros in decimal places if whole number in ssrs expression but would like to retain 2 decimal places if not zero?

```
Sample data Value -> Value displayed in SSRS

59.00 -> 59
65.00 -> 65
87.39 -> 87.39
68.49 -> 68.49
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format the textboxes using an expression, so something like this should work.

Set the `Format` property to ...

```
=IIF(Fields.myFieldName.Value = CINT(Fields.myFieldName.Value), "f0", "f2")
```

This just basically says, if it's an integer, show 0 decimal places, otherwise show 2 decimal places.